# blockUI works but unBlockUI Isn't

Tags: jquery, ajax, blockui

I've implemented block UI as this request can take a little, time when the ajax request starts everything works as expected.

But when the ajax request finishes and the msgbox is shown, the UI doesn't unblock!

Any ideas?

I'm using IE8.

```
$().ajaxStart($.blockUI); 
$().ajaxStop($.unblockUI); 

function ChangeCompanyState(companyId, state) {
    var parameters = "{companyId:" + companyId + ",state:\"" + state + "\"}";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Ajax/AjaxFragments.aspx/ChangeCompanyState",
        data: parameters,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            if (msg.d.length > 1) {
                alert(msg.d);
                $.unblockUI();
            }
            else {
                //Theres no message to process success.
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As told [here](http://listly.net/jquery-en.googlegroups.com/ie-blockui-incompatible.html), using

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

seems to fix the problem. I didn't get any other way to solve it in my own project.

Answer (score 8):

```
$.unblockUI();
$(".blockUI").fadeOut("slow");
```

Comment: +1 This solution just saved me from a huge headache. Thanks!!

Comment: It's a workaround but worked perfectly. I wrapped the second line with

`if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 9) {`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same, and resolved by using parentesis in unbluckUI sentence.

```
// block when ajax activity starts
function beginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    $.blockUI({ message: '<h1><img src="loading.gif" /> Just a moment...</h1>' });
}

// unblock when ajax activity stops 
function endRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    $.unblockUI(); // previously was $.unblockUI;
}
```

HTH
Milton

Comment: makes sense indeed, without them you are not actually calling the function. Documentation states otherwise however, this works.