# Calling unblockUI in ajax success callback not working (IE 8)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, jquery-blockui

I have the following code that I'm running on every page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI);
    $(document).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);
    $("form").submit(function() {
        if ($(this).valid() == true) {
            $.blockUI();
        }
    });
});
```

This code allows me to present a "loading..." message during both AJAX calls and form posts.  In general, this is working fine.  However, I have a scenario in which I need to make an AJAX call to validate a piece of data prior to making a form post, as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Item/VerifyFolder/',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        folderName: folderName
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $.unblockUI(); 
        if (data.folderItemExists == true)
        {
            $("form").submit();
        }
        else
        {
            if (confirm("The folder specified for this item does not exist.  Do you want to create it?") == true)
                {
                    // ...
                    $("form").submit();
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            DisplayError(textStatus);
        }
    });
```

In my AJAX success callback, I start off by calling `$.unblockUI()`.  However, it seems to have no effect.  As a result, the "loading..." message is still displayed when the alert pops up.

I've seen various posts online about problems with IE 8 and the unblockUI method (misformed HTML, needing a meta tag, etc) but I have yet to find a solution that works.

Any guidance would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in the AJAX success callback:

```
$.unblockUI();
$(".blockUI").fadeOut("slow");
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1661872/1315626